# How unique are checksums?

Tags: files, checksum

I have a lot of files I need sorting; and sadly there are many files with the same name but different content, and there are the same content with different filenames.

I'm thinking about using `md5sum` to generate checksums for the files, but I need to know - is it possible that two different files (ie. different content) will generate the same checksum?

If it is, how likely is it to happen?

Would it be possible to use two different unrelated (ie. not in the same "family") checksum-programs to generate two checksums - under the assumption that while two different files may generate the same checksum for either one of the checksum-programs, it would never happen to both at once?

Comment: Remember md5/sha2/etc is a HASH of data thus mapping a lot bits of information to a smaller bit space, thus it is possible there might be collisions.  A HASH is not a unique key and if that is your goal...I'd strongly recommend to do something else.

Comment: For sorting files, MD5 is fine.  From https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/18337/49945, probability of checksum collision of two different contents is 1 in 2^128 which is about 1 in 10^43.  That's really, really rare. If you do one comparison per microsecond, on average you would get a collision once in 10^20 years. Its only been ~10^9 years since Big Bang, so the odds of a collision happening EVEN A SINGLE TIME, at one comparison per microsecond from Big Bang till now is still only 1 in 10^11. Given a hundred billion simultaneous computers, only ~one would have seen a collision yet.

Comment: ... though it isn't clear why you would use any hash algorithm when sorting files. If there are files with same name, they must be identifiable by some other criteria; e.g. there must be some *unique path* to the file, or perhaps a *byte offset* within some storage device?  Either of those would be a more useful way to uniquely refer to the file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Two files with same contents but different filenames:** (*file1* and *file2*):

```
cat file1
this is a simple file

cat file2
this is a simple file

md5sum file1
7de45bf879db49de7e2eacea23e6c165  file1
md5sum file2
7de45bf879db49de7e2eacea23e6c165  file2
```

**Two files with different contents but same filenames:** (*file1* and *file1*)

```
cat file1
this is a simple file
cat file1
this is a simple file with extra contents
md5sum file1 #first file1
7de45bf879db49de7e2eacea23e6c165  file1
md5sum file1 #second file1
c7c8f3fd9ddd7a926c31416a69063e4e  file1
```

From the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum) entry,

> However, it is very unlikely that any two non-identical files in the
>   real world will have the same MD5 hash, unless they have been
>   specifically created to have the same hash.

But, the [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) algorithm has it's own flaws.

> However, now that it is easy to generate MD5 collisions, it is
>   possible for the person who created the file to create a second file
>   with the same checksum, so this technique cannot protect against some
>   forms of malicious tampering. Also, in some cases, the checksum cannot
>   be trusted (for example, if it was obtained over the same channel as
>   the downloaded file), in which case MD5 can only provide
>   error-checking functionality: it will recognize a corrupt or
>   incomplete download, which becomes more likely when downloading larger
>   files.

I would recommend using sha1 for calculating the checksum since producing collisions is not that easy when using [sha1](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19705/is-sha1-better-than-md5-only-because-it-generates-a-hash-of-160-bits) algorithms. Producing sha1 checksum is pretty easy as you can see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61826/how-do-i-check-the-sha1-hash-of-a-file).

Comment: NOTE: the question is about *sorting* files; the recommendation to use `sha1` is not relevant to that task; it only matters when concerned about *security*.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve  Sorting by an essentially random key is futile. I suspect "sorting" here means "sorting out the mess" rather than "arranging in some strict sequence". I once got tasked with identifying a set of 16,000 image files which had been unreliably pushed out to 160 fat-client servers over several years of updates. Grouping them by checksum, and having them vote on the most likely correct version, was a lifesaver (literally -- it was HV electrical SCADA system).

Comment: @Paul_Pedant - Yes indeed. My comment is simply that this answer did not need to recommend sha1 rather than MD5 - that is a security recommendation. For "sorting out the mess", security is irrelevant; *any* algorithm that generates a large enough hash value (with a sufficiently random distribution; crypto algorithms are appropriate because they distribute hash values well) such that collisions are very rare works fine.